# get value outside request callback

Tags: node.js

I am learning nodejs and stuck . Need your help. When I run function getSessionKey() function... I am able to log session key inside request call back but not able to log it outside request. Please help me how can access it outside.

```
function getSessionKey(){
var key = '';
var tempObj = {method:'',id:0,params:{username:'',password:''}};
tempObj.id = 1;
tempObj.params.username = 'test';
tempObj.params.password = 'test';
tempObj.method = 'get_session_key';
options.body = JSON.stringify(tempObj);
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            var keyObj = JSON.parse(body);
            key = keyObj.result;
            console.log(key); //here I am able to access key
          });
//console.log(key); //but I want to get it here.
}
getSessionKey()
```

Comment: You don't.  You learn how to program asynchronously where you use asynchronous results only in the async callback itself or in a function you call from there.  This is how async programming works in nodejs.

Comment: Thank you.. I will review other thread where this similar question is answered.